# Identifying a 6 pin and a 18 pin WSON IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, texas-instruments

I have a couple of the following ICs, which I suspect to be some DC/DC converter possibly from TI, but I could not find the exact part number. It is a 6 pin, WSON package IC with a thermal pad.

The top says:

```
48D6K
L197B
```

[image]
[image]

---

The other IC is a 11 pin QFN one where 8 pins are GND and connected to a thermal pad. It is also suspected to be some kind of DC/DC converter from TI.

The top says:

```
SBL
TI 481
A052
```

`T1` or `TI` I am not sure.

[image]
[image]

Both ICs were acquired about 4-5 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L197B is a 6 pin WSON package, not QFN.
[LM2832](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snvs455a/snvs455a.pdf?ts=1609442338886&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) has this marking in 6 pin WSON.

The second one is a 11 pin VSON package.
In which case it would be a [TPS61232DRCR/TPS61232DRCT](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61232.pdf?ts=1609443132711&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS61232)